# changing from base 3 to base 9 using given information

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> (a) Given a sequence of non negative integers $\{a_r\}$ show that
>
> 1. $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^na_r(x+1)^r(\!\bmod x)=\sum_{r=0}^na_r(\!\bmod x)$ where $x\in\{2,3,4,\ldots\}$.
> 2. $\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^n(3a_{2r+1}+a_{2r})9^r=\sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}a_r3^r$
>
> (b) Hence determine whether the base $3$ number $22010112200201$ is divisible by $8$.

For part (b), I really don't know where to start. It is a hence question but I fail to see how one can use answers from part a to solve the question.

Please help...

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The second part of (a) says that you can break $22010112200201$ into two-digit chunks, $(22)(01)(01)(12)(20)(02)(01)$, convert each chunk into a base nine digit, and get the base nine representation of the number:

$$22010112200201_{\text{three}}=8115621_{\text{nine}}\;.$$

Now apply the first part of (a) with $x=8$.

**Added:** To expand a little on the second part of (a), suppose that $m$ is a positive integer whose base three representation is $(a_{2n+1}a_{2n}a_{2n-1}\ldots a_1a_0)_{\text{three}}$. By definition this means that

$$m=\sum_{r=0}^{2n+1}a_r3^r\;.$$

Now divide the digits in this representation into pairs: $(a_{2n+1}a_{2n})(a_{2n-1}a_{2n-2})\ldots(a_1a_0)$. These pairs are of the form $(a_{2r+1}a_{2r}$ for $r=0,1,\ldots,n$. Replace the $r$-th pair, $(a_{2r+1}a_{2r})$, by the single digit $3a_{2r+1}+a_{2r}$; you can easily check that the result will always be one of the digits $0$ through $8$, so it will be a possible digit for a number written in base nine. Call this digit $d_r$; then the string $(d_nd_{n-1},\ldots d_1d_0)_{\text{nine}}$ is the base nine representation of the number

$$\sum_{r=0}^nd_r9^r=\sum_{r=0}^n(3a_{2r+1}+a_{2r})9^r\;,$$

and the second part of (a) says that this is equal to the number $m$ with which we started.

In other words, converting a number from base three to base nine is very easy: it’s just a matter of starting at the righthand end and converting each pair of adjacent base three digits into a corresponding base nine digit.

Comment: May  you explain to where how the second part of (a) suggest I can break the number into two-digit chunks. I have problem understanding the notation and what it suggests :(

Comment: @ladygaga1995: Here $n=6$, so $2n+1=13$. $22010112200201_{\text{three}}$ is $\sum_{r=0}^{13}a_r3^r$, where $a_{13}=2$, $a_{12}=2$, $a_{11}=0$, $a_{10}=1$, and so on down to $a_1=0$ and $a_0=1$. Now take $r=6$, say; then $3a_{2r+1}+a_{2r}=3a_{13}+a_{12}=3\cdot2+2=8$, the leftmost digit of the base nine number.